# C# SqlDataReader release profile closing dataReader early (Error)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqldatareader

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(command, myConnection);
using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        Item item = new Item();
        try { cost = double.Parse(myReader["Cost"].ToString()); } catch { /* logging */ }
        item.Cost = cost;
        list.Add(item);
    }
}

return list;
```

I have the above code, when ran in Debug mode it executes perfectly, however when I switch visual studio to Release profile, it only returns a list of about 500 items, when it should be 3-4x that.

My SQLClass creates and opens a new SqlConnection (myConnection) upon creation of the class, and disposes it in a destructor.

I can find no references elsewhere of this type of behavior, however it works flawlessly in Debug. I have catch statements around it to try and catch an error, it occasionally throws a 'sqlDataReader closed' error, however most of the time it doesn't even throw an error. Really hard bug to replicate, however in release in a brand new project, it still returns a list of less than correct dataset.

I've replicated the bug creating a brand new class library with the problem code. Building the dll in release mode gives zero problems. If I run the test console application in debug, it works fine (Even with compiled dll from release mode) However debug mode fails to return the correct number of results.

Comment: Is the empty `catch` shown a typo or is that really in the code?

Comment: This is not an answer, but instead of `try { cost = double.Parse(myReader["Cost"].ToString()); } catch { }` use `double.TryParse`

Comment: i shrank the code a bit to just show the problem, with a single example variable. The catch has some simple error logging in the real code

Comment: I guess, that you should initialize new item to add on every read in a `while` loop. Now you just change a property in object already created, which is in fact the same object throughout the process. Try `item = new Item(){Cost = cost}`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn hi sorry, my apologizes the original code does contain the item initialization already. i will update the original post to reflect this.

Comment: You should put `myCommand` in a `using` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Turns out the class destructor method was being called while the while(myReader.Read()) is still executing, which was causing it to error or only return half of the data, before the connection was forcibly closed by the destructor. The Code optimization of Release candidate must have meant the glass was disposed before the reader was finished.

Fixed it by removing the

```
    ~SqlClass()
    {
       myConnection.Close(); // This was causing all the issues.
    }
```

From the destructor class, which fixed the issue. Now just relying on the GC to clean up the SqlConnection class.

Comment: Your code doesn't have anything in it referring to a `SqlClass`.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/20/77460.aspx may be worth a read. `One of the guidelines for finalization is that a Finalize method shouldn't touch other objects.`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting remarks from comments together, I came up with the code, which you should try:

```
int cost = 0;
Item item;
while (myReader.Read())
{
    double.TryParse(myReader["Cost"].ToString(), out cost);
    item = new Item(){Cost = cost};
    list.Add(item);
}
```